# Modify one of array value, resulted in all array value recalculate in angular animation

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, transition

I generated 16 cells and ideal is that clicking each cell show a circle with animation when the circle element entering and leaving. 
I met two issues in this case:
1) transition is not working when the circle leaving.
2) quickly adding and removing a circle sometimes results in another circle rerendering.

[my code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-void-animation-problem)

app.component.html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="circlecell" *ngFor="let circle of circles; let i=index" data-id="{{i}}" (click)="OnShow(i)">
          <div class="circle" [@show] *ngIf="circle"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition,
  // ...
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  animations:[
      trigger('show',[
          state('in',style({
              backgroundColor: 'red'
          })),
          transition('void=>*',[
            style({
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                transform: 'scale(0)'
            }),
            animate(1000,style({
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                transform: 'scale(1.5)'
            })),
            animate(500)
          ]),
          transition('*=>void',[
            animate(1000,style({
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                transform: 'scale(0)'
            }))
          ])
      ]),
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

    circles:(boolean)[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        for(let i =0;i<16;i++){
          this.circles.push(false);
        };
    }

    OnShow(index){
      this.circles[index] = !this.circles[index];  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I should add a trackby, without adding a trackby, ngFor can not track correct cell.